# How to create an MVC attribute which takes a variable sent in the Route attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got a variable being sent into my controller via RoutePrefix Attribute

```
[RoutePrefix("{cultureName}/store-locator")]
public class StoreController : Controller
{ // controller stuff }
```

What I'm trying to do is create another Attribute that takes the value of  `cultureName` and does stuff with it. The actual logic of that attribute is easy enough, I'm just not sure how to get the cultureName value into my attribute.

I created my HandleCulture Attribute

```
public class HandleCulture : System.Attribute
{

    public HandleCulture(string cultureName)
    {
        // Creates a CultureInfo object from the culture code
        var culture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);

        // Sets the current culture for the MVC application
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
    }
}
```

But when I add it to my controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("{cultureName}/store-locator")]
[HandleCulture(cultureName)]
public class StoreController : Controller
{ //controller }
```

cultureName isn't defined.

Comment: Use `[HandleCulture(Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["cultureName"].ToString())]` .

Comment: Hmmm, I love the idea (I didn't think of using Request) but Request isn't static and so I can't use it in an attribute

Comment: In that case, I think you can do this by remove the parameter from Constructor and use `var culture = new CultureInfo(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["cultureName"]);`